# edit xml file using c#,getting error invalid token

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, namespaces, xml-namespaces

My Problem Is My XML file having Two namespace ,so i cant change text of xml in SelectingNode Method

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\test.xml");
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(reader); //Assuming reader is your XmlReader
                    XmlNamespaceManager oManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                    oManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com//sqlserver//reporting//2005/01//reportdefinition");
                    oManager.AddNamespace("rd", "http://schemas.microsoft.com//SQLServer//reporting//reportdesigner");           
                    doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Report/ns:buttons/ns:workshop1", oManager).InnerText = "new text";
                    reader.Close();
                    doc.Save(@"C:\\test.xml");
```

Xml File is Having More than One namespace so problem is here icant resolve it.

and my XML file is

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <buttons>
    <workshop1>Google</workshop1>
    <url1>www.google.co.uk</url1>
  </buttons>
</Report>
```

Comment: You only need to double up backslashes if you don't use a `@`, and you don't need to double up forward slashes at all. So the following all represent a single slash: `"\\"`, `@"\"`, `"/"`. Things like `@"\\"` or `"//"` represent double slashes. Not sure if that's the root of your issue, but it can't be helping.

Comment: Actually Problem is Because I have Two Namespace in my xml file,so in My c# code i dont knw how to access workshop1 node using SelectingNode method

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Error msg is NullReferenceexception Is unhandled By Code.Object reference not set to an Instance of an object

Comment: please help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Could somebody plz give me code how to edit xml inner text in which xml file having more than one namspace

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @MatthewStrawbridge in comment, the problem is the prefixes declared pointing to incorrect namespace URL. You don't need to escape forward slashes, so the prefix that point to default namespace should be declared this way :

```
oManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");
```

Then your could work just fine to change value of `<workshop1>` element to `"new text"`. You don't even need to declare the second prefix mapping in the code, because you don't use it.