# Change the inner text of Xml file using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML file which has the namespace as shown...

I have to change the inner text of XML file but need suggestion how to do it.

My XML file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
      <buttons>
        <workshop1>Google</workshop1>
<workshop1>Yahoo</workshop1>
        <url1>www.google.co.uk</url1>
      </buttons>
    </Report>
```

I have to change the inner text of second node `workshop1` from "Yahoo" to "new".

Comment: possible duplicate of [edit xml file using c#,getting error invalid token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309010/edit-xml-file-using-c-getting-error-invalid-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this using XElement.

The "problem" you probably had is due to the namespace this xml has:

```
    XElement xml = getXml(); // get your xml from a service\file\ftp etc..
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition";
    xml.Descendants(ns + "workshop1").First().Value = "new";
```

Your output:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <buttons>
    <workshop1>new</workshop1>
    <url1>www.google.co.uk</url1>
  </buttons>
</Report>
```

For more than one node use this:

```
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition";
    var nodes = xml.Descendants(ns + "workshop1").ToList();
    nodes[0].Value = "new";
    nodes[1].Value = "new2"; 
    // etc....
```

Comment: Bt what if i have same node two times in xml file.for example if i have <workshop1>google</workshop1><workshop1>new</workshop1>,and i have to change second node workshop1 from "new" to "new text"..how to do this..

Comment: can i add new node in my xml file after </buttons> node. for example i have to add following xml text : <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT FirstName,Lastname FROM Person</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="FirstName">
          <DataField>FirstName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Lastname">
          <DataField>Lastname</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
  </Fields>

Comment: Please note that here my second namespace in xml file is used by node <rd:TypeName>